# getting multiple company names from their respective ticker

Tags: python, loops, stock, yahoo-finance, yfinance

Just looking for a return, where I can input ticker symbols and receive a list of the full company names:

```
list = ['MSFT','HIVE','etc','etc']
```

`ticker(list)` will return list of company names

Comment: so what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```py
import yfinance as yf

ticker_list = ['MSFT','HIVE', "AAPL", "HOOD", "TSLA", "GOOG"]


def ticker(ticker_list):
    com_name = []
    for ticker in ticker_list:
        stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        name = stock.info.get('longName')
        com_name.append(name)
    return com_name


com_name_list = ticker(ticker_list)
print(com_name_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['Microsoft Corporation', 'HIVE Blockchain Technologies Ltd.', 'Apple Inc.', 'Robinhood Markets, Inc.', 'Tesla, Inc.', 'Alphabet Inc.']
```

> You have to install `yfinance` to run this code.

yfinance installation command: `pip install yfinance`